# Excel to Pandas DataFrame using first column as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very simple table in Excel that I'm trying to read into a DataFrame

[image: Excel data]

Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('params.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=None)
```

This results in the following DataFrame:

[image: DataFrame]

I didn't expect param1.key to become the index, especially after having set `index_col=None`. Is there a way to get the data into a DataFrame with a generated index instead of the data from the first column?

Update — here's what happens when you try `reset_index()` to resolve the issue:

[image: DataFrame after reset_index()]

Version info:

- Python 3.5.0
- pandas (0.17.1)
- xlrd (0.9.4)

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. In any case, you can always do `reset_index()` to remediate.

Comment: Reported it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11733

Comment: @joris Thanks for reporting the bug. I tried the `reset_index()` before posting, thinking it would solve the issue. While the index is indeed reset, the labels are still messed up (see screenshot in updated question).

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, it sees the ('param1', 'key') as the level names of the columns .. Do you have a large dataframe? I can try to come up with some complicated code to clean this up automatically, but if it is rather small dataframe, probably easier to just put the correct column names by hand

Comment: @joris It's a small one, no worries. Thanks for the offer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug. You can get a column out of your index by simply doing:

```
df['columnName'] = df.index
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

```py
# just use col order number in the `index_col` field, 0-indexed
df = pd.read_excel('yourFile.xlsx',index_col=0)
```